# What’s this pipe outlet looking thing on the wall below sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain

Is this what’s known as a drum trap? What do I need to do with this?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, that is a drain clean-out. If you unscrew the cover, you get a fairly straight shot to your main sewer line. This way, if you get a clog (often tree roots penetrating the pipe) in your sewer pipe leading to your municipal waste system, you can get tools (rotary cleaners, inspection cameras, etc.) into the line.

Just leave it be and make sure you can get at it if necessary.

Comment: And if you open it when the sink is plugged and full, everything above it will drain out into the room.

Comment: @LeeSam Very true if the clog is below the clean out, not above.